# No application knows how to open Homestead.yaml

Tags: laravel

I am installing Laravel homestead 2 here where I first initialized the file with `homestead init` so when I tried to edit it it gave me this error...how can fix this so I can edit the file ? thanks in advance!

homestead edit

```
No application knows how to open  /Users/MyUserName/.homestead/Homestead.yaml
```

Comment: Just open Homestead.yaml with any text editor or your IDE to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because your computer doesn’t know what you want to edit the YAML file with. If you want to stay in the terminal and update it you will just need to nano or vim the Homestead.yaml file, or to make it so you can use homestead edit, simply set your computer to always open .yaml files with a certain editor. For example, I set mine to open in PHPStorm.